# Meteor fontawesome dropdown menu open on start

Tags: meteor, font-awesome, dropdown

I have this html page using meteor and fontawesome packages. When I open this page I have all the dropdown-menu opened and when I click one of the down arrow they all close. I make a lot of try to close those pannels, but all try stop the correct hide/display of the pannels.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{> loginButtons }}
        {{> userList }}
</div>
</body>

<template name="userList">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        <div id="userList" class = "panel panel-default"> 
            <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
            <ul class = "list-group">
                {{#each user in allUser}}
                    {{#with user}}
                        <li class="user list-group-item >{{> userOptions }}</li>
                    {{/with}}
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>


<template name="userOptions">
    <div class="btn-group open">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> {{username}} </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            <span class="fa fa-caret-down" title="Toggle dropdown menu"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban fa-fw"></i> Ban</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Make admin</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

I see they have css display:block. On the console i try to write `$(".dropdown-menu").toggle()` and it work, but after i can't open the dropdown menu

Comment: Can you post the javascript for these templates - need to see how you are handling the events. I'm guessing your events aren't scoped to the template instance - so clicking one dropdown makes them all open. This will make more sense with your events map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove open from `<div class="btn-group open">` if you don't want it to open by default.

Comment: OMG! yes it was just this ... we have to read code one bilions of time before ask ...